# jade template ignoring first space on line after pipe symbol

Tags: pug, templating

I have a minor detail question regarding jade templates

I'm seeing the following template:

```
p(data-ng-show="submitting")
 i.icon-cog.icon-spin
 | Authenticating...
```

being converted to this HTML

```
<p data-ng-show="submitting"><i class="icon-cog icon-spin"></i>Authenticating...</p>
```

Note the single space before "Authenticating..." is not carried over into the compiled HTML. Is the only solution here to use   to force a white space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how Jade is supposed to work, and I know, it's veeery bad having to deal with such a thing.

You can do this:

```
p(data-ng-show="submitting")
 i.icon-cog.icon-spin
 |  Authenticating...
```

which I think is somewhat tricky.

Another option is to print an whitespace HTML entity, as already suggested by @brnrd:

```
p(data-ng-show="submitting")
  i.icon-cog.icon-spin
  | &nbsp;Authenticating...
```

*Yet another option*, but very bad in my opinion (or not that much if you use i18n), is:

```
p(data-ng-show="submitting")
  i.icon-cog.icon-spin
  = " Authenticating..."
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a white space character :

```
&nbsp;
```

As :

```
p(data-ng-show="submitting")
  i.icon-cog.icon-spin
  | &nbsp;Authenticating...
```

It does the trick.